# Gerar todas as trocas de letras possíveis em uma palavra

Tags: python-3.x, string

Preciso criar uma função que gere todas as possiveis trocas de letras que gerem palavras com o mesmo som:

```
Palavra: Feijoada
Possibilidades: Feigoada, Feyjoada, Feijoada, Feygoada
```

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso, minha função retorna apenas uma palavra:

```
Feigoada
```

**Código:**

```
word = input()
word = word.lower()
cont = 0

letterlist = []
wordslist = []

for letter in word:
    letterlist.append(letter)
while cont < 6:
    if "c" not in letterlist:
        pass
    else:
        word2 = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter == "c":
                letter = "k"
                word2 = word2+letter
            else:
                word2 = word2+letter
        if word2 in wordslist:
            pass
        else:
            wordslist.append(word2)

    if "k" not in letterlist:
        pass
    else:
        word2 = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter == "k":
                letter = "c"
                word2 = word2+letter
            else:
                word2 = word2+letter
        if word2 in wordslist:
            pass
        else:
            wordslist.append(word2)

    if "m" not in letterlist:
        pass
    else:
        word2 = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter == "m":
                letter = "n"
                word2 = word2+letter
            else:
                word2 = word2+letter
        if word2 in wordslist:
            pass
        else:
            wordslist.append(word2)

    if "n" not in letterlist:
        pass
    else:
        word2 = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter == "n":
                letter = "m"
                word2 = word2+letter
            else:
                word2 = word2+letter
        if word2 in wordslist:
            pass
        else:
            wordslist.append(word2)

    if "j" not in letterlist:
        pass
    else:
        word2 = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter == "j":
                letter = "g"
                word2 = word2+letter
            else:
                word2 = word2+letter
        if word2 in wordslist:
            pass
        else:
            wordslist.append(word2)

    if "g" not in letterlist:
        pass
    else:
        word2 = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter == "g":
                letter = "j"
                word2 = word2+letter
            else:
                word2 = word2+letter
        if word2 in wordslist:
            pass
        else:
            wordslist.append(word2)
    cont += 1
```

O que posso estar errando nesse código? Existe alguma biblioteca que já faça esse trabalho?

Comment: 'Feijoada' e 'Feigoada' nao possuem o mesmo som..
Essa troca de J por G deve ser implementada apenas caso a letra venha antes de  'e' ou 'i', não?

Comment: Eu tinha feito só com algumas letras inicialmente. Não tinha parado para pensar a respeito certinho do G e J. Muito obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No código existem apenas os tratamentos para as letras (C e K), (M e N) e (J e G).
  Não existe o tratamento para (I e Y) por exemplo. Precisa criá-lo.
- Outro detalhes, nao pode trocar o J pelo G em todas as palavras.. apenas as que tenham **e** ou **i** após a letra... Feijoada nao tem o mesmo som de Feigoada.